# can't add images with jsPDF when using node.js

Tags: node.js, jspdf

jsPDF works well within node, but adding an images does not work. There are no error messages, the images just don't show up in the pdf document.

Working with:
macOS:  **10.13.4**
nodejs: **v10.15.0**
jsPDF:  **1.4.1**

The code I use:

```
// setting up node to act as browser
// library jspdf is built for the browser
// global.window does not work on older versions of node

global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}}}};
global.navigator = {};
global.btoa = () => {};
global.node = true;

var fs = require('fs');
atob = require('atob') // npm install atob
var jsPDF = require('/absolute/path/to/jspdf.js');
var pdf = new jsPDF

var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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'


pdf.setFontSize(40)
pdf.text(35, 25, 'Some Sample Text')
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160)

fs.writeFileSync('my_image_pdf_test.pdf', pdf.output());
```

The pdf file is larger when the image is added (97806 bytes).
Without the image it is just 2448 bytes.

What can be wrong? Any node packages missing?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that when you write pdf files with images in nodejs, you have to use `pdf.output('arraybuffer')`

So replace the following line:

```
fs.writeFileSync('my_image_pdf_test.pdf', pdf.output());
```

with:

```
fs.appendFileSync('another_image_pdf_test.pdf', new Buffer.from(pdf.output('arraybuffer')));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answering your own question. This helped me. :)